# how can i do this codes work only in a specific div tags

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(":input").focusout(function () {
    var a= $(this).closest("tr").attr('id');
    var b= $(this).closest("td").attr('id');
        var c = $(this).attr("value");


    $.post("database.php", { trAdress:a , tdAdress:b, value:c});

    });
});
```

could this code work only between `<div i="bab"> </div>` tags...

Comment: What does *could this code work only between tags* mean? If you describe your problem better, you get better answers (or answers at all). Currently it is not clear what you want. Take your time and explain your problem properly.

Comment: between what tags? you can combine selectors, i.e. `$("#mydiv :input")` will apply only to input elements within `mydiv`

Comment: I mean, this focusout function must work only specific part of code... in specific input tags...as example, I have 9 inputs but this focusout must work only in 6 inputs

Comment: so just a class `foo` to the inputs which you want to target and change the markup to `<input class="foo" />` and do `$(":input.foo")`

Comment: $("#mydiv :input") .... this worked correctly... thanks dude...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you really need to read about jQuery and how it works .. i suggest you start here

http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

In your code this line :

```
$(":input").focusout(function () {
```

is a selector `$(':input')` - which selects part of the DOM
and a method `focusout` - the method performs an action on the selected element, in your case adds an event listener. You can select just about anything on the DOM ... [read this section of the docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

If you have the following HTML (or something like it)

```
<div id="bab">
 <input etc.... />
</div>
```

you could use `$('#bab :input')` as your selector (descendant selector) - this would get all `input` elements within the `div` with an id of `bab` (`#` means use the id selector)

Answer (score 2):

yes! change

```
$(":input")
```

to

```
$("#bab :input")
```